# How to tell what methods are available in a installed module

Tags: python, module

If I do a `print(dir(pychromecast))` at a Python prompt, I get the list at the bottom of this message. Which of the methods are supposed to work? Because some do, like `pychromecast.get_device_status()` But others like `_get_chromecast_from_host` or `get_chromecasts` throw an attribute error like:

```
AttributeError: module 'pychromecast' has no attribute 'get_chromehosts'
```

Is it that I am doing/understanding something fundamentally wrong? Does the `_` before the name play into it?

As promised, here is the output of dir:

```
['APP_BACKDROP', 'APP_DASHCAST', 'APP_MEDIA_RECEIVER', 'APP_PLEX',
 'APP_SPOTIFY', 'APP_YOUTUBE', 'CAST_TYPES', 'CAST_TYPE_CHROMECAST',
 'Chromecast', 'ChromecastConnectionError', 'ControllerNotRegistered',
 'DeviceStatus', 'IDLE_APP_ID', 'IGNORE_CEC', 'LaunchError',
 'MultipleChromecastsFoundError', 'NoChromecastFoundError', 'NotConnected',
 'PyChromecastError', 'PyChromecastStopped', 'STREAM_TYPE_BUFFERED', 
 'UnsupportedNamespace', '_LOGGER', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__cached__',
 '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', 
 '__path__', '__spec__', '__version__', '__version_info__', 
 '_get_chromecast_from_host', '_get_chromecast_from_service', 
 'cast_channel_pb2', 'config', 'controllers', 'dial', 
 'discover_chromecasts', 'discovery', 'error', 'fnmatch', 'get_app_config', 
 'get_chromecasts', 'get_device_status', 'get_possible_app_ids', 'json', 
 'logging', 'reboot', 'requests', 'socket_client', 'start_discovery',
 'stop_discovery', 'threading']
```

Comment: Are you including parentheses after `_get_chromecast_from_host` like so: `_get_chromecast_from_host()`?

Comment: Yes, I keep hoping that I can get chromecast to directly attach to a device rather than going through it's slow discovery process, so I have been plugging an ip address into the () on all the modules that look like they might have something to do with connecting to a chromecast device. Also tried it empty(). Some, like get_device_status() will accept an ip address. Thanks for the hint though. this is a scantly documented python library.

Answer (score 2):

> But others like `_get_chromecast_from_host` or `get_chromecasts` throw an attribute error like ...

Part of the problem would seem to be a typo. You mention `get_chromecasts`, but your exception line mentions chrome*hosts*:

> AttributeError: module 'pychromecast' has no attribute 'get_chrome**hosts**'

Is it possible you had a typo in calling `_get_chromecast_from_host` as well, or provided wrong arguments? Could you please provide the specific exception for that function call?

Comment: @NickolasStevenson-Molnar it took me a while to understand what you meant, but I finally figured out that I had randomly cut and pasted one of the error messages. I was just experimenting to see if I could somehow find a magic phrase that would work, looking back now that was pretty stupid. Anyway, nice catch.

Comment: @RobertBaker Ok, so you're saying that you _have_ tried `get_chromecasts` and it _doesn't_ work?

Answer (score 1):

They should all "work". Some of them will be methods and some will be variables though. Have you tried `_get_chromecast_from_host` **and**  `_get_chromecast_from_host()`? As for the _ or __ in front of the attribute that means it is protected and you probably shouldn't be directly modifying it, although just reading it should be fine. At least that's my understanding :)